# Google Cloud Service Account Refresh token

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm looking for a good way to solve my issue at hand.

I'm working on a solution where remote devices needs access to some google cloud functionality as well as access to my backend service.

In my head I envision it like this:

---

The remote devices uses a service account **through** a refresh token.

Meaning I want to be able to let my server generate a refresh token on **behalf** of the service account that will be used by the remote device.

This refresh token will then be used bu the remote device to authenticate to google services such as storage etc, as well as the backend API.

This refresh token can be stored in the backend and revoked if ever needed.

If possible I'd like to attach subject to the refresh token so that I can know which device it is since the auth is defined by a single service account.

---

So:

- The device does not have a end user that signs in.
- The deice needs access to google services + my API

I've yet to find good documentation on this. The backend is written in JS/TS and client is written in python.

Is this possible?

Comment: Service accounts do not provide refresh tokens. The tokens are short-lived (3600 seconds) and must be recreated when they expire.

Comment: Why do you need an access token? If you want to add the subject it's an identity token (JWT) that you need. But the expiration constraint is the same.You have to request a new token every hour (see john comment). Optionally, if you use access token, you can imagine storing the refresh token and use it to generate a new access token on demand.

Comment: Right. I might be able to utilise the subject/JWT solution for some parts.

I've got too many units up for having multiple SA:s. I'll treat the devices as a kind of user in my backend. For all google related services the devices has to ask for a SA key to talk to google services.